# How to Load Data into Hive from HDFS

Tags: hadoop

I am Trying to load data into hive from HDFS . But I Observed that data is moving , meaning after loading the data into hive environment if i look at the HDFS the data which i have loaded is not present . can You Please answer this question with example .

Comment: could you tell us which command or query you are using for loading data.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to create a table in Hive from data in HDFS without moving the data into `/user/hive/warehouse/`, you should use the optional `EXTERNAL` and `LOCATION` keywords.  For example, from [this page](http://pyfunc.blogspot.com/2012/03/external-tables-in-hive-are-handy.html), we have the following example `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
hive>   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE userline(line STRING) ROW FORMAT
              DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
              LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
              STORED AS TEXTFILE
              LOCATION '/home/admin/userdata';
```

Without those, Hive will take your data from HDFS and load it into `/user/hive/warehouse` (and if the table is dropped, the data is also deleted).